# How go to another Tab, but keep the previous tab

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I am use BottomNavigationView. For Example:

TAB_1 Screen_1 -> Screen_2

TAB_2 Screen3

TAB_3
Screen_4

I want to go from Screen_2 to Screen_3 and I go back to TAB_1, I want to see Screen_2

How can I do this?

In my Activity

```
 val bottomNavigate = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.mainButtonNavigation)
 val navController =
        (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.containerGuestView) as NavHostFragment).navController
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigate, navController)
```

In Screen_2 when I click to go to Screen_3

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_global_tournamentTableGuestFragment)
```

Comment: What version of Navigation are you using? Navigation 2.4 does this automatically as per the [multiple back stacks blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/multiple-back-stacks-b714d974f134).

Comment: i use only navigtion version = "2.4.0-alpha10" without alpha version fragment

Answer (score 1):

I add this in my Activity and it worked

```
    val bottomNavigate = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.mainButtonNavigation)
    val navController =
        (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.containerGuestView) as NavHostFragment).navController
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigate, navController)
    bottomNavigate.setOnItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.graph_guest_leagues -> { //This is TAB_1 in Example
                navController.apply {
                    navigate(R.id.graph_guest_leagues)
                    navigate(R.id.action_leaguesFragment_to_divisionsFragment) //This is Screen_2 in Example
                }
            }
            R.id.tournamentTableGuestFragment -> navController.navigate(it.itemId)
            R.id.matchesGuestFragment -> navController.navigate(it.itemId)
            R.id.favoriteFragment -> navController.navigate(it.itemId)
        }
        true
    }
```